# VB.Net: How to Redirecting Input to Java process?

Tags: java, vb.net, input, redirect

When I run the program the I am unable to send any commands to the java process. If I make 'MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe"' it works, and I'm able to send commands as if it were normal cmd. Is there another way to redirect the input or am i doing something wronge?

```
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents MyProcess As Process
Private Delegate Sub AppendOutputTextDelegate(ByVal text As String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.AcceptButton = Button1
    MyProcess = New Process

    With MyProcess.StartInfo
        .WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\PJ\games\Minecraft\Server\Craftbukkit 1.6.4 Server"
        .FileName = "java.exe"
        .Arguments = "-Xmx3G -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true"
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
    End With
    MyProcess.Start()
    MyProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()

    AppendOutputText("Process Started at: " & MyProcess.StartTime.ToString)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    MyProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("EXIT") 'send an EXIT command to the Command Prompt
    MyProcess.StandardInput.Flush()
    MyProcess.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub MyProcess_ErrorDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MyProcess.ErrorDataReceived
    AppendOutputText(vbCrLf & e.Data)
End Sub


Private Sub MyProcess_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MyProcess.OutputDataReceived
    AppendOutputText(vbCrLf & e.Data)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
    MyProcess.StandardInput.Flush()
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub AppendOutputText(ByVal text As String)
    If TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim myDelegate As New AppendOutputTextDelegate(AddressOf AppendOutputText)
        Me.Invoke(myDelegate, text)
    Else
        TextBox1.AppendText(text)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest sending data between processes, by executing the second using a shell and giving arguments. I would suggest two ways to send data between a vb.net and a java application.

1. Web service interface

The java process could be a server accepting requests with data from the vb.net application. The interface could be a [SOAP](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fafb4ca-4a47-4554-8d25-f1b23d572ef7/soap-examples) or a [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx) interface.

1. CORBA-RMI interface

Using CORBA you could send data between two processes. [Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2004/jw-0517-javanet.html) you could start reading about CORBA and java and .NET interoperability.

Following these architectures has an additional advantage too. The java process and the vb.net process could be located on different computers.

Hope I helped!